# Is there a way to execute non-blocking load_job from BigQuery Python Client library?

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a Flask API that uses Flask_restful, Flask_CORS and Marshmallow. The API does some work to get a *.csv file into Cloud Storage (using signedURL's), confirms that it has uploaded, and then creates and executes a load job to transfer the csv from Storage to BigQuery.
The part of the API that is exacerbating my hair loss is the call to execute a load job in GCP that loads a csv file to BigQuery. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
...
            dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset(target_dataset) 
            job_config.schema =  bq_schema 
            job_config.source_format = SOURCE_FORMAT 
            job_config.field_delimiter =  DELIM  
            job_config.destination_table_description = TARGET_TABLE
            job_config.encoding = ENCODING 
            job_config.max_bad_records = MAX_BAD_RECORDS
            job_config.autodetect = False # Do not autodetect schema
            load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(
                uri, dataset_ref.table(target_table), job_config=job_config
            )  # API request
            load_job.result() # **<-- This is the concern**
            return {"message": "Successfully uploaded to Bigquery"}, 200
```

The file can  take some time to transfer, and my concern is that during periods where there is some latency, the webserver will timeout whilst waiting for the transfer to take place. I would much prefer to have `load_job.result()` execute, get the job ID and return a 201 response. Then I can use the job ID to poll GCP to determine whether it was successful or not, rather than have there be a risk of the request timing out for the client-side front-end and leave the user confused as to whether it succeeded or not.

I understand that load_job.result() is async, but with Flask that doesn't help. I was going to change over to Quart to use async/await but my other dependencies are not supported and therefore I will have a lot of refactoring to do. Is there another way that anyone has used to approach this type of problem?
Cheers

Comment: I will reformulate just to be sure on what do you want to do: You want to use Quart for running the load job in async mode and then to use a callback when the job is finished?

Comment: That is what I wanted to do, but Quart doesn't support flask_cors or flask_restful so I am looking for alternatives. So far I am leaning towards just using RQ and have a task queue to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quart solves nothing. Indeed, Quart still needs to a running environment, it waits and oversees the blocking function and calls you callback at the end. Your function must still running for performing this.

There is a better design for this. I recommend you to have a look to [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks). The process is the following:

- Run  your load job
- Create your task with the load job ID in parameter
- Exit the function
- Task will trigger another function that will check if the job is over

  - If not yet finish, return an error code (different than 2XX).
  - If finish, return a OK return code (2XX)

You have to set up your Cloud Task with [retry policy](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues#retry) to not retry immediately (for example set the `min-backoff` to 30s)

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. I didn't know about Cloud Tasks. I had tried two solutions. One was using PubSub to trigger a Cloud Function. Finally, I set up a task queue using Redis and RQ. With Cloud Tasks are you tied in or is it possible to do a lift and shift to either a self hosted or another cloud solution? Main reason is that some customers may already have an on premise solution or another Cloud Provider and want to stick with what they know.

Comment: Cloud Task product is tied to Google Cloud. It was previously embedded into App Engine, it has been extracted for being used by the other products, but it's still an internal product to Google Cloud. However, it's not a too smart tool: Get a URL and perform a HTTP call. If fail, retry it according with the retry policy, else close the task. I'm sure that many equivalent product exist.

Comment: Ok thanks Guillaume. I believe the gist of the solution is to make use of task queues in some form.